# Clean undeployment of a Grails application in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, profiling, classloader

At the moment every time I re-deploy an application the old webclassloader is kept because of a blocking thread called Timer-0 which is started by hibernate, I think.
I tried to analyze a heap dump with YourKit but there are several thousend classes still loaded and it is hard for me to figure out what is blocking the classloader.

This leaves me with a few questions:

- How to find the reason the classloader can't unload?
- Is there a best practice to make sure everything is unloaded completely without restarting the container?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

Sample Datasource:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
    username = "xx"
    password = "xx"
    configClass = DdlFilterConfiguration
    properties {
        maxActive = 250
        maxIdle = 25
        minIdle = 1
        initialSize = 10
        maxWait = 10000
        validationQuery = "select 1 "
        validationQueryTimeout = 3
        validationInterval = 15000
        testOnReturn = true
        testWhileIdle = true
        testOnBorrow = true

        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, restart the container. :/

Comment: I have done successful Parallel Deployment using Tomcat 7 and Grails.  Which is like a redeploy without any downtime.

Comment: How are you doing your DB connection pool?

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I thought there might be a way to avoid this as there could be applications running in this container which rely on 24/7 uptime.

Comment: @Joe There are several DataSources pooling with different drivers (Informix, Postgres). I've updated the Question with a configuration we use.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach is to front end the system with a Proxy (Apache Proxy works well).  You could have two Tomcat instances even on the same machine but on different ports lets say 7001 and 8001. Lets say you are currently running on port 7001 you start your new deploy on 8001 and then repoint your proxy to the 8001.